# Generating a random number not working on live server

Tags: php

This has baffled me for several hours now. Below is the code in question. It works totally fine on my local server but when migrated to the live server, the problem I'm seeing is the random number that is generated and stored as int type (the same as on local) isn't random at all. All of the entries have the exact same number (2147483647).

I don't know why it works locally but won't on the live server. It's the exact version of PHP. I've researched this for a few hours now and can't find a thing.

I'm sure this is some simple oversight and figured posting it here, one of you brilliant minded developers could point it out?

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_POST['submit'])) 
{
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$first_name = ucwords(addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['firstName'])));
$last_name = ucwords(addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['lastName'])));
$age = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['age']));
$location = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['state']));
$description = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['desc']));
$date_added = date("Y-m-d");
$aka = ucwords(addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['aka'])));

$offender_id = mt_rand(1, 99999999999);

//offense pertinent 
$date_of_offense = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['date_of_offense']));
$offense = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['offense']));
$added_by = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['added_by']));

if(empty($aka))
{
    $aka='None Known';
}


if($first_name&&$last_name&&$age&&$location&&$description&&$date_of_offense&&$offense&&$added_by)
   {
       include('../includes/db_cred.php');

        $sql = "INSERT INTO offenders VALUES ('', '0', '$offender_id', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$aka', '$age', '$location', '$description', 'na', 'na', 'na', '$added_by', '$date_added')";
```

Comment: Note that your `max` value in your `mt_rand` call is well above the possible maximum value, which just so happens to be `2147483647`. I also assume `$offender_id` should be unique in which case I do not recommend generating random numbers for those.

Comment: Thanks sir! That should fix it and thanks for the tip.

Comment: What is interesting is that `mt_rand` on your local machine accepts larger than 2^32 for the range, but the server does not.

Comment: It just so happened that in testing, the value stored was never above that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making the following PHP call:

```
$offender_id = mt_rand(1, 99999999999);
```

However, the maximum value which `mt_rand()` appears to be capable of accepting on your server is 2^32 = 2147483647, which is the value you keep seeing.

From the PHP manual:

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed)